# Clustering QtLocation markers technique

Tags: qt, qml, mapbox, gis, qtlocation

Currently, I'm using this project https://github.com/OpenGeoscience/vtkMap based on the VTK framework to have a slippy map in which I can add markers and group them in clusters. I have already contributed to that project but there's still bugs in it and it does not fit my requirements (on the visual aspect).

So, I want to use Qt maps instead of vtkMap, but I didn't find a way/an example to create marker clusters. Apparently, it's a complex task to achieve (as I already fixed some bugs in vtkMap clustering system) and I want to know how people deal with that problem with QtLocation/QML.

Comment: what exactly do you mean saying _marker clusters_? can you provide your attempt to do that in QML?

Comment: @folibis I found this https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52301?attachmentOrder=desc but the guy removed his clustering algorithm from the source code that he attached (in void ClusterableModel::doRecalculation()). It's strange that QLocation lacks stuff that is common in other technologies (Leaflet, Google Maps Android API,...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found QGeoView a C++/Qt map (no QML BS). I started coding a class "placemarker" that handles a set of POIs and that support clustering : https://github.com/embeddedmz/QGeoView/blob/draft/demo/samples/placemarkSetLayer.h

Otherwise, someone can look at the clustering logic of my class and use it a QML map.